# Recyclerview design issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview to show my order items but it has design issue and after 3 days changing it I have no other solution for it!

`screenshot`

[image: one]

#### Issues

1. Recyclerview is not covering page full height
2. Items have space same as recyclerview height (it shows 1 item per page!)

#### Code

`fragment_order.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/orderItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.OrdersFragment">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/orders_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

`order_items.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:background="@color/orders"
                android:layout_width="4dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_Iid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:text="@string/order_ID"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_status_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:text="@string/order_status"
                android:textColor="#5CDCBD"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_price_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:text="@string/price"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`OrdersFragment.kt`

```
class OrdersFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var sesssion: SessionManager
    lateinit var laundriesRecycler: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false)
        sesssion = SessionManager(context)
        laundriesRecycler = root.findViewById(R.id.orders_list)
        getOrders()
        return root
    }

    private fun getOrders() {
        var session = SessionManager(context)
        session.checkLogin()
        var user = session.getUserDetails()
        var token: String? = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        val tokenFull = "Bearer $token"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/orders"

        val stringReq : StringRequest =
                object : StringRequest(
                        Method.GET, url,
                        Response.Listener { response ->
                            val list = Gson().fromJson(response, OrderArr::class.java)
                            laundriesRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                            laundriesRecycler.adapter = OrdersAdapter(context, list)
                        },
                        Response.ErrorListener {
                            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show()
                        }
                ){
                    override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                        headers["Authorization"] = tokenFull
                        return headers
                    }
                }
        queue.add(stringReq)
    }
}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

`OrdersAdapter.kt`

```
class OrdersAdapter(
        val context: Context?,
        private var orderList: OrderArr
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.orders_items,
                parent,
                false
        )
        //fixing width issue
        val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        val display = parent.display
        display?.getRealMetrics(outMetrics)
        itemView.layoutParams = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(outMetrics.widthPixels, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        return OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = orderList.data[position]
        holder.orderId.text = "ID: " + currentItem.id
        holder.price.text = if(currentItem.amount!= null){"Rp. " + currentItem.amount + " /KG"}else{"Not provided"}
        holder.status.text = if(currentItem.lastProgress!= null) {currentItem.lastProgress.progress.name} else{"Unknown"}

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val i: Intent = Intent(context, OrdersActivity::class.java)
            i.putExtra("orderIDArgument", currentItem.id.toString())
            it.context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = orderList.data.size

    class OrderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val orderId: TextView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_Iid)
        val status: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_status_text)
        val price: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_price_text)
    }
}
```

## Update 2

`Activity_main.xml`

> Every fragment will replace each other inside this activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentFragmentId"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graphs"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />
    </ScrollView>

    <!--bottom navigation bar with items-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryNewTheme"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryNewTheme"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="14dp"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        tools:ignore="BottomAppBar,MissingConstraints" />

    <!--Floating action button which is anchored to the bottom navigation button-->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryNewTheme"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/order"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryNewTheme"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

#### Update 3

`fragment_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.MainFragment">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header_imageP"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/himage"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/main_header"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="@string/nameHint" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/useremail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="@string/emailHint" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/useremail"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/himage"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/t1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/header_imageP"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                        android:text="HIIII" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/t2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                        android:text="BYEEEE" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post RecyclerView Adapter class ? And how do you load OrdersFragment ? I mean are you using Fragment transition or Navigation Component ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA ok I will update my question, and yes I am using navigations.

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA updated.

Comment: Why are you using         itemView.layoutParams = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(outMetrics.widthPixels, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA some how my items weren't full width and that fixed the width issue of items

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA no idea?

Comment: You do not have use `RecyclerView.LayoutParams` . Also why are you using `FrameLayout` inside Card View ?this will overlap the views use Linear or Constraints whichever fits your design.

Comment: @ADM can you share answer to point me where I should make changes please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove code for customizing width and height of recycler item view inside Adapter.
Like:

```
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder {
  val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
          R.layout.order_item,
          parent,
          false
  )
  //fixing width issue
  /*val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
  val display = parent.display
  display?.getRealMetrics(outMetrics)
  itemView.layoutParams = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(outMetrics.widthPixels, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)*/
  return OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

Second, you are not putting any constraint to `FragmentContainerView` thats why it goes to `(0,0)` position by default and you have set it's height to `wrap_content`, so your recycler view looks like the posted image. And it is not recommended to use recycler view inside scroll view. Try with customizing Activity_main.xml as below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
    app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="14dp"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
    tools:ignore="BottomAppBar,MissingConstraints"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graphs" />

    <!-- put FAB here -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What's the second? cause by that I just lose full width items and nothing changes about heights

Comment: Next comming to your Recycler view height issue, first post your activity layout xml file my friend.

Comment: It is the parent container of RecyclerView which decides the Height . So.. post you Activity's xml file where you load fragment .

Comment: I am getting proper full screen height and width of recycler view and all it's items.

Comment: I do get proper full screen as well but I also get scroll issue in my main fragment when I scroll (this fragment is when app opens) see screenshot here https://ibb.co/vhy86Sv

Comment: Scroll issue ? Are you able to scroll recycler view item till last ?

Comment: yes recyclerview is fine, it just caused issue in my main fragment as you see in my screenshot

Comment: Can I see main fragment's layout file ?

Comment: I dont have clear idea about how you are managing all fragments my friend, I just solve your recycler view issue. Try to set proper constraint and see layout preview before run app.

Comment: I've share my main fragment, and I'm aware that you helped me to fix recyclerview issue that's why i've votedup for you, but that caused another issue (can't create 1 issue to solve other you know what i mean?)

Comment: @mafortis don't use scrollview in `activity_main` use it in which fragment you needed and my suggestion is not to use scrollview as a container of recyclerview. You can use `NestedScrollView` instead

Comment: I've already deleted it from activity_main based on your code, but I will redesign my main fragment see if fixes it, thank you so much\